# Use non-static method as source for Task

Tags: c#, multithreading, task

I was using `Thread` class to create one more thread of execution. Like this:

```
/// <summary>
/// This method is executed in parallel thread (NON-static!)
/// </summary>
private void SomeMethod()
{
    // some actions
}

var thread = new Thread(SomeMethod);
thread.Start();
```

But now I need have ability to cancel executing of `SomeMethod` in runtime. So I try to use `Task` class and its cancellation mechanism.
And when I try to pass `SomeMethod` as argument into Task constructor like this

```
private Task _task = new Task(SomeMethod);
```

I have this compile error:

***cannot access non-static method 'SomeMethod' in static context***

I cannot make `SomeMethod` static, it is impossible for many reasons.
 As I know, `Task` class surpasses `Thread` class, so this is very strange limitations I think. 
 Is it possible to use non-static methods as source for `Task`?

Comment: fyi, that has nothing to do with Tasks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a constructor:

```
private Task _task;

public YourClassName()
{
   this._task = new Task(this.SomeMethod);
}
```

Comment: It works, my fault, I try like this: 

private Task _task = new Task(this.SomeMethod); <<-- wrong

Answer (score 0):

You can also use a lambda expression.

```
private void SomeMethod() {
    // some actions
}

Task task = new Task(() => {
    SomeMethod();
});
task.Start();
```

Comment: What is the compiler error? If you have the method in a class, and are creating the task in another method, then I do not see an error at the moment.

Comment: In another method it will work, but in your answer it looks like creating `Task` in declaration.

Comment: You mean that I wrote it just like you did in your example? :-)